# Img Extends Beyond Parent Div

Tags: wordpress, image, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a custom theme for my blog using bootstrap 3 and I got most of it to work but on my posts I have a problem where my images extend outside the main content area over the sidebar on the right!

I am using 
`<div class="span8">` for main content and a `<div class="span4">` for the sidebar.
in my stylesheet I have added...

```
.span8 img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
}
```

but that does not seem to work!
I have also looked on the getbootstrap.com website under the images section but there is nothing there as well!

Let me know if you wish to view the site and I will be more than happy to provide a link! Many thanks!

Comment: try to narrow down the issue to specific areas in your code and paste it into your question, also, try using a code pasting service like http://www.bootply.com/new for example so that you can reproduce the issue and paste it into your question in addition...

Comment: Use the bootstarp classes like ex: `row`, `col-sm-X`, ect (X is in range 1-12; but it depends on screen you target) for the main content of the site; also study hard [the examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples).
But in general first try to construct a good example of your problem like @webeno mentions, then post it; [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a good start.

Comment: @Egel `spanX` is the naming convention of Bootstrap 2, so I assumed the OP is using that, `col-sm-X` is Bootstrap 3... as to pasting the code, http://www.bootply.com/new is probably really the best in this case as you don't have to deal with including bootstrap related css and js...

Comment: Yes @webeno, you've got completely right (I don't even knew of existing of this site; thank you) but main problem was to show the problem in working example.

Comment: @webeno Except he says he's using Bootstrap 3 right there in the question. Which might be the problem. Phillip, are you using trying to use Bootstrap 2 code with Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @MattGibson you're absolutely correct, I totally missed that; it might be the cause (or at least part of it)...

Answer (score 4):

Change to :-

```
.span8 img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

This is a browser issue in some it will work but others will require the width: auto

Comment: Thats awesome thanks for that works on in Chrome but in FF its still the same! might have to flush my dns

Comment: could be just the cache a right click refresh usually does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap provides an `img-responsive` class which you can apply to your images.

```
<img src="#" class="img-responsive" />
```

This applies `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

**Ref:** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: Yea noticed that Henry that was on the bootstrap website! I got thousands of images though! The answer provided by Barry above yours works fine though!

Comment: That's the problem with `img-responsive`. Also, it adds extra markup which can be avoided if you use Barry's solution.

Comment: Yep weirdly I have used barrys solution and it's working fine in chrome but in FF and IE even adfter flushing the dns and changing ip addys its still doing the same!

Comment: Is `style.css` loading before or after `bootstrap.min.css`? Not sure if this will matter in this case but try making sure `style.css` loads last.

Comment: Yea think so! my style css is in the root ducument an dnot in the bootstrap folder!

Comment: How are you loading `bootstrap.min.css` and `style.css`? Are you using `wp_enqueue_scripts` or are you just adding them to `<head>` manually?